# Parsing response from SOLR

Tags: java, json, solr

```
{responseHeader={status=0,QTime=0,params={q=ketan,wt=[javabin,javabin],version=2.2}},response={numFound=1,start=0,docs=[SolrDocument[{user_first_name=Ketan, customerid=5,killname=Hockey, areaname=Paud, categoryname=Sports, last_name=Kore, statename=Maharashtra, cityname=Pune, contactno=124555698}]]}}
```

I have recieved this response SOLR and want to get JSONObject SOlr Document from this.
Please help me how to parse this response.

Answer (score 0):

The string you mentioned is a json string (json is Javascript Object Notation). Try using java-json lib for decoding it. [Here is an example](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use hash map to make JSONObject , solrj doesn't support json format as output as of now

Answer (score 0):

I found this post quite useful. Though it's quite when this question was asked but it might help others also as I was got the same issue. I resolved this issue using Google API for JSON - GSON.

The response that Solr give is not in JSON format. We need to convert it.
I retrieved the response from solr and converted it to json object.

Originally, my response was:

```
   {docs=[SolrDocument{id=1, uuid=7fe08f79-e184-454d-908f-08b32583a822, packName=Workflow Logger-Pack, packDescription=Workflow Logger-Pack, packAuthor=NetApp, packVersion=1.0.0, packDate=May 22, 2014, 3:10 pm, entityName=[Workflow Logger, Wait, Logging cmd, Test cmd for multiple Parameter Types], entityDescription=[Workflow Logger, Wait Command, Logging command, Test cmd for multiple Parameter Types], entityType=[Workflow, Command, Command, Command], _version_=1468794552324194304}, SolrDocument{id=2, uuid=7fe08f79-e184-454d-908f-08b32583a822, packName=Workflow Logger-Pack New, packDescription=Workflow Logger-Pack, packAuthor=NetApp, packVersion=2.0.0, packDate=May 22, 2014, 3:13 pm, entityName=[Workflow Logger, Wait, Logging cmd, Test cmd for multiple Parameter Types], entityDescription=[Workflow Logger, Wait Command, Logging command, Test cmd for multiple Parameter Types], entityType=[Workflow, Command, Command, Command], _version_=1468794760693022720}, SolrDocument{id=3, uuid=7fe08f79-e184-454d-908f-08b32583a822, packName=Workflow Logger-Packs updated, packDescription=Workflow Logger-Pack, packAuthor=NetApp, packVersion=3.0.0, packDate=May 22, 2014, 3:32 pm, entityName=[Workflow Logger, Wait, Logging cmd, Test cmd for multiple Parameter Types], entityDescription=[Workflow Logger, Wait Command, Logging command, Test cmd for multiple Parameter Types], entityType=[Workflow, Command, Command, Command], _version_=1468795898385399808}, SolrDocument{id=5, uuid=7fe08f79-e184-454d-908f-08b32583a822, packName=Workflow Logger-Pack New, packDescription=Workflow Logger-Pack, packAuthor=NetApp, packVersion=2.0.0, packDate=June 17, 2014, 7:02 am, entityName=[Workflow Logger, Wait, Logging cmd, Test cmd for multiple Parameter Types], entityDescription=[Workflow Logger, Wait Command, Logging command, Test cmd for multiple Parameter Types], entityType=[Workflow, Command, Command, Command], _version_=1471140110510587904}]}
```

My code:

```
 HttpSolrServer server= new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");
        server.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());

        Gson gson= new Gson();

        SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();
        solrQuery.setQuery("*:*");

        solrQuery.setHighlight(true);

        solrQuery.setHighlightRequireFieldMatch(true);
        QueryResponse response= server.query(solrQuery);
        SolrDocumentList docs = response.getResults();

        String res= gson.toJson(docs);
        System.out.println(res);
```

Now, it is converted to JSON as:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "uuid": "7fe08f79-e184-454d-908f-08b32583a822",
    "packName": "Workflow Logger-Pack",
    "packDescription": "Workflow Logger-Pack",
    "packAuthor": "NetApp",
    "packVersion": "1.0.0",
    "packDate": "May 22, 2014, 3:10 pm",
    "entityName": [
      "Workflow Logger",
      "Wait",
      "Logging cmd",
      "Test cmd for multiple Parameter Types"
    ],
    "entityDescription": [
      "Workflow Logger",
      "Wait Command",
      "Logging command",
      "Test cmd for multiple Parameter Types"
    ],
    "entityType": [
      "Workflow",
      "Command",
      "Command",
      "Command"
    ],
    "_version_": 1468794552324194300
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "uuid": "7fe08f79-e184-454d-908f-08b32583a822",
    "packName": "Workflow Logger-Pack New",
    "packDescription": "Workflow Logger-Pack",
    "packAuthor": "NetApp",
    "packVersion": "2.0.0",
    "packDate": "May 22, 2014, 3:13 pm",
    "entityName": [
      "Workflow Logger",
      "Wait",
      "Logging cmd",
      "Test cmd for multiple Parameter Types"
    ],
    "entityDescription": [
      "Workflow Logger",
      "Wait Command",
      "Logging command",
      "Test cmd for multiple Parameter Types"
    ],
    "entityType": [
      "Workflow",
      "Command",
      "Command",
      "Command"
    ],
    "_version_": 1468794760693022700
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "uuid": "7fe08f79-e184-454d-908f-08b32583a822",
    "packName": "Workflow Logger-Packs updated",
    "packDescription": "Workflow Logger-Pack",
    "packAuthor": "NetApp",
    "packVersion": "3.0.0",
    "packDate": "May 22, 2014, 3:32 pm",
    "entityName": [
      "Workflow Logger",
      "Wait",
      "Logging cmd",
      "Test cmd for multiple Parameter Types"
    ],
    "entityDescription": [
      "Workflow Logger",
      "Wait Command",
      "Logging command",
      "Test cmd for multiple Parameter Types"
    ],
    "entityType": [
      "Workflow",
      "Command",
      "Command",
      "Command"
    ],
    "_version_": 1468795898385399800
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "uuid": "7fe08f79-e184-454d-908f-08b32583a822",
    "packName": "Workflow Logger-Pack New",
    "packDescription": "Workflow Logger-Pack",
    "packAuthor": "NetApp",
    "packVersion": "2.0.0",
    "packDate": "June 17, 2014, 7:02 am",
    "entityName": [
      "Workflow Logger",
      "Wait",
      "Logging cmd",
      "Test cmd for multiple Parameter Types"
    ],
    "entityDescription": [
      "Workflow Logger",
      "Wait Command",
      "Logging command",
      "Test cmd for multiple Parameter Types"
    ],
    "entityType": [
      "Workflow",
      "Command",
      "Command",
      "Command"
    ],
    "_version_": 1471140110510588000
  }
]
```

Hope it helps.